# Different folder and web structure

Tags: web-development

Is it possible to keep a different folder structure than the web structure that users see when browsing the website?

I.e. I want all my main pages to be accessed the following way:
**www.example.com/main-page-1/**

Do I need to necessarily have each page in a separate folder, or can I keep all them in the same folder and define the structure somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with [URL Rewriting](http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/).

The following tutorial explains what URL rewriting is, how to get started with Apache and IIS web servers, as well as a number of useful examples.

- [URL Rewriting for Beginners](http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)

Answer (score 0):

More dynamically, you can use a single PHP file displaying the content of your static files. You can re-write the urls to whatever you like. By this method, you can avoid general codes (e.g. header, footer, etc) to be repeated in every single file.